# How do I target css styling to other browsers except for IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am trying to target a particular styling for all browsers except for ie9 and below.

I did this to target IE9 and below:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/ie.min.css">
    <![endif]-->
```

I do not recall what would be the other way to target all other browsers except for IE9. I do recall there is a way to do it like I did to target IE9 and below but I do not recall.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't adding what you have above and a regular `<link rel=stylesheet....` address your issue? If it is IE9 it will use the specific stylesheet for it, otherwise every other browser would use the other?

Comment: You'd still need to hide the "every other browser" stylesheet from IE 9 and below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/ie.min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/ie-9.min.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normal.min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This method should provide you with separate stylesheets for less than IE 9, IE 9, and more than IE 9 (including all non-IE browsers). The trick for the last conditional is `<!-->` and `<!--<!`, which cause Edge and non-IE browsers to interpret the `if` and `endif` as separate comments.

To target a single version in particular, use `<!--[if IE #]>`.

As pointed out by [jkdev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661772/how-do-i-target-css-styling-to-other-browsers-except-for-ie9/38662337#comment64740221_38662337), since IE 9 is the last version to support conditional comments, the last conditional could have been written:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normal.min.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The result would be the same as the first snippet: only IE 10-11, Edge, and non-IE browsers would get `css/normal.min.css`. None of the earlier IE versions would get this file since they would evaluate `if !IE`.

Comment: Remember that [conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) are only recognized by IE versions 5 through 9; any other browser is considered "downlevel" and ignores conditional comments. So instead of `if gt IE 9` you could use `if !IE`.

Comment: @jkdev Quite right. It's a style preference, I suppose. I'll edit in a comment about that.

Comment: Thank You All. You all have helped increase my knowledge. I appreciate it